# How to send verification email from server to client's register email

Tags: meteor

I am using meteor for developing my application. I need to verify user as soon as he register himself. I used SendverificationEmail() method of meteor and i m getting link on the server side . Now i want to send that unique link to the client's register email. How it will done?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use meteor Email package to send email:
[Meteor Email Package](https://docs.meteor.com/api/email.html)

After you have added package just write below code in your method to send an email

```
Email.send({ to, from, subject, text });
```

Comment: I think the author of the question wanted to ask something else. Can you please refer to latest answer and see what I have posted.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to See this post little late, but there are many folks out there who are willing to implement this even today. So below are the steps to achieve email verification flow.

> **NOTE:**  I am using Meteor 1.6.1.1, with Flow-routers + Blaze Templates. Also, make sure you have enabled 3rd party API access call to Gmail. You can do this from Gmail settings.
>
> **Import Packages**: accounts-ui, accounts-password

In `root_folder/server/` folder, inside `main.js` copy paste below code and make the necessary credential change to your file.

```
var username = 'asdasdasdas'; 
var password = 'sdasdasdasd';
var server = 'smtp.gmail.com';
var port = '465';

process.env.MAIL_URL = 'smtps://' +
encodeURIComponent(username) + ':' +
encodeURIComponent(password) + '@' +
encodeURIComponent(server) + ':' + port;

process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = 0;

Accounts.emailTemplates.from = 'support_team@domain.com';

//-- Application name
Accounts.emailTemplates.siteName = 'Your Site Name';

//-- Subject line of the email.
Accounts.emailTemplates.verifyEmail.subject = function(user) {
    return 'Email Confirmation.';
};

//-- Email text
Accounts.emailTemplates.verifyEmail.text = function(user, url) {
    var newUrl = url.replace('/#','');
    return 'Thank you for registering.  Please click on the following link to verify your email address: \r\n' + newUrl;
};

// Configure to send the Email Verification mail as true
Accounts.config({
    sendVerificationEmail: true,
    restrictCreationByEmailDomain: function(email) {
        var domain = email.slice(email.lastIndexOf("@")+1); // or regex
        var allowed = ["gmail.com", "yahoo.co.in", "outlook.com", "yahoo.com", "yandex.com", "protonmail.com", "protonmail.ch", ];
        return _.contains(allowed, domain);
      },
    loginExpirationInDays: 1
});
```

When you successfully create an account in Meteor app, you will get an email as below;

[image]

Inside the mail, You will see a link with route of pattern `/verify-email/:token`, hence go inside `project/client/routes.js` you need to add the route,

```
 import { FlowRouter } from 'meteor/kadira:flow-router';

//force user to stay on home page instead of desired page
Accounts.onLogin(function(user){
  var user = Meteor.user();
  if(user.emails && user.emails[0].verified){
    FlowRouter.go('dashboard');
  }
});

FlowRouter.route('/verify-email/:tokenId', {
  name: 'verify-email',
  action: function(params, queryParams) {
    var token = FlowRouter.getParam("tokenId");
    console.log(token);
    Accounts.verifyEmail(token, function(err){
      if(!err){
        FlowRouter.go("dashboard");
      } else {
        FlowRouter.go("error-page");
      } 
    });
    
  },
});
```

In case if you are using iron-router, you can refer this [LINK](https://github.com/joshterrill/meteor-email)